# Replace MacBook Air 11-in SSD with the 13-in's SSD

Tags: ssd, macbook, macbook-air

Is it possible to replace the Macbook Air 11-in's SSD with the 13-in's SSD ? (since the SSD in the 13-in model is 2x faster, looks like they are the same size...)

*Latest models - early 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this you can:

http://www.engadget.com/2015/03/12/macbook-air-samsung-ssd/

It might be more cost effective to buy a similar SSD off the shelf though, M.2 is a normal standard and you can probably find something with similar specs for way cheaper than if you got it from another MacBook. Say this is 512gb and similar write/read:

[http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-XP941-512GB-AHCI-80mm/dp/B00JOSM3TK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JOSM3TK)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I was looking if anyone actually tried it. Btw I don't think any off the shelf drives would work though.